# Foreach to change a key

Tags: php

I retrieve a set of mysql row as an array of associative arrays (I'm using pdo fetch all). My associative arrays holds a key named "password". How do I loop throught the arrays to change all the password values? I need to set them to 0 if the password is equal to 0, 1 instead.

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/* gotta strip all the password, I can't send them! */
foreach($result as $res)   $res['password'] = (!$res['password']) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: You can use `+!!$res['password']` instead of `(!$res['password']) ? 0 : 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about usinf a **`&`** in the `foreach` :

```
foreach($result as & $res) {
    $res['password'] = (!$res['password']) ? 0 : 1; 
}
```

And, as a precaution, you might want that `foreach` loop to be followed by this `unset()` instruction, to break the reference with the last element of your array :

```
unset($res);
```

As a reference, quoting [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

> you can easily modify array's elements by preceding $value with `&`.
>   
> This will assign reference instead of copying the value.

And there is a note about the `unset()` a bit later on that same manual page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for it! But... isn't referencing going to be deprecated?

Comment: I don't see why it would be, at least in the case of a foreach, where it's usefull *(it is useful : it's a solution to this question ;-) )* -- one thing *(related to `&`)* that is deprecated is using it at call-time for functions, but it's not what we are doing here.

Comment: @hysoka44: Only pass-by-reference is deprecated (or discouraged).

Comment: referencing can sometimes be useful (for lazy old-style programmers)

Answer (score 1):

Foreach allows you to have a reference to the current value (`&` operator), so  it's an alias to the value you want to change. You then have it already "at hand".

Next to referencing the current element, you can reference the password value as well:

```
foreach($result as &$res) {
    $password = &$res['password'];
    $password = (int)(bool) $password;
}    
unset($res, $password);
```

If you do not want to use references and prefer to work on a copy of the data, you can achieve this easily with `array_map`:

```
$result = array_map(function($res)
{
    $res['password'] = (int)(bool) $res['password'];
    return $res;
}, $result);
```

Or if you want to directly work on the original array w/o references:

```
foreach($result as $key => $res)
{
    $result[$key]['password'] = (int)(bool) $result[$key]['password'];
}
```

You can find this variant often in older PHP code as foreach and references were not possible in the past, however it's not really easy to read.

Comment: Thanks!! I like your last solution!